# Meaning of “l'étage … ne peut le désigner”

Tags: sens

Here is a paragraph [from Wikipedia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89tage_%28architecture%29):

> Dans un bâtiment, l'étage est en élévation au-dessus du
>   rez-de-chaussée et ne peut le désigner.

In English it means:

> In a building, the floor is elevated above the ground floor and can
>   not designate.

I don't understand the last part: why an étage could not be designated?

Comment: With http://fr.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89tage_%28architecture%29 the link works best, at the minimum for moi.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this sentence, I think that *le* refers to *rez-de-chaussée*. They simply want to say that the *rez-de-chaussée* cannot be designated as an *étage*. You can say *1er étage*, *2e étage* but *l'étage du rez-de-chaussée* would be false. The *rez-de-chaussée* is not an *étage*.

I found some [advises/directives from the Swiss administration](http://www.bfs.admin.ch/bfs/portal/fr/index/news/00/00/10/02.parsys.68496.downloadList.3755.DownloadFile.tmp/richtlinief.pdf) for this.

> **Numérotation de 
>   l'étage** Les étages sont par principe désignés par un numéro croissant (de 0 à
>   89). La désignation de l'étage n'est cependant  pas attribuée au
>   rez-de-chaussée car la numérotation ne peut  pas commencer par un
>   zéro.

Answer (score 4):

> Dans un bâtiment, l'étage est en élévation au-dessus du rez-de-chaussée et ne peut le désigner.

I would translate it by “In a building, ‘*étages*” are elevated above the ground floor, which they cannot designate.” I.e., an “étage” is above the ground floor but the ground floor is **not** an “étage”. You could translate ”*étage*” by “floor”, but they aren’t exactly the same thing and it would make little sense to by that the ground *floor* is not a *floor*.

The term “storey” might be more accurate to translate “étage” as it excludes the ground floor, although it seems it is sometime used to designate basements, which are not called “étages” in french.

The “premier étage” in particular is not what the american call “first floor“.

Architects often use the word “*niveau*” (“level”), which include both “*étages*” and “*rez-de-chaussé*” (and “*sous-sols*”, “*entresol*“, “*rez-de-jardin*“, etc.).

> *Un triplex est un appartement qui s’étend sur trois niveaux.*

Because one of those levels could be the ground floor, you shouldn’t use “étages” here.

So in short: an “étage” is a floor which is *above* the ground floor excluding the ground floor. It is, in particular, not a basement.

Comment: @douard thank you :) not a native english speaker, now i got it that "storey != floor" -- for years i thought the two are interchangable :p

Answer (score 2):

The first clause is about the concept of *étage*, while the second clause is about the word *étage*. It's a bit confusing, I had to read the sentence twice and I'm a native speaker.

> Dans un bâtiment, l'étage est en élévation au-dessus du rez-de-chaussée.

In a building, an *étage* is somewhere above the ground floor. The word *étage* means a floor that is above ground level, unless the context strongly indicates otherwise. For example, in a two-storey building, you could say “*je suis au rez-de-chaussée*” or “*je suis en bas*” to mean “I'm downstairs”, and “*je suis à l'étage*” or “*je suis en haut*” to mean “I'm upstairs”. If you say that a house has “*un étage*”, it means it has a floor above the ground floor: it's a two-storey building. The *premier étage* is the first floor above the ground floor (like British usage, and unlike American usage). Note that [Québec tends to follow American usage](http://www.dufrancaisaufrancais.com/a-quel-etage-le-premier-etage/).

> L'étage [...] ne peut le désigner.

*Le* refers to *le rez-de-chaussée*. This clause means that the word *étage* cannot be used to mean the ground floor. It isn't that the *étage* cannot be designated, but that *étage* cannot designate the *rez-de-chaussée*.

Comment: thanks, you know what, if you read the line twice, i was like "i'm not that stupid" :p